# How to setup user login, authentication and authorisation AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have been reading a lot of documentation and can't for the life of me work out how to do this.

I have setup AWS API Gateway to trigger a Lambda function that gets data from a DynamoDB database.
I want to setup secure access to the API methods.
I have created a user account in an AWS Cognito User Pool and created a Federated Identity pool using Cognito.

I have worked out that I need to do these things:

1. Login
2. getId
3. getCredentialsForIdentity

I understand set 2 and 3 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html)
What I don't know is now to login to get the tokens I need.

I want my users to be able to login using an SDK or REST API. I can only find information about using the Facebook SDK to login but nothing about how to login to AWS Cognito itself.

I want my user to do something along the lines of this:

- token = login(username, password);
- id = getId(token);
- credentials = getCredentialsForIdentity(id);
- data = getItemFromDB(credentials,query);

What am I missing? They claim this whole Cognito thing is suppose to simplify things but it seems overly complicated to me. I just want simple security for my API.

Answer (score 2):

If all that you want is to secure your API using cognito user pool is, the best starting point will be the following page:

[Using Cognito User Pools as Authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)

This tells you how to integrate an API with user pool. In case you need to know about how to integrate your web application with cognito user pool, one option is to use Javascript. Please refer the following for examples on accessing Cognito services from Javascript.

[Accessing Cognito Services from Javascript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)

For this, you may need to include amazon-cognito-identity.min.js and aws-cognito-sdk.min.js in your front end code.